# Link to another page using Twitter Bootstrap jquery modal in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I just want this modal to come up and display the contents of another page but i cannot get it to work as I am new to Jquery. Is there a way to modify the code below in order to bring up the contents of '/contact/' in the modal popup?

```
----------
# this content is on http://myurl.com/contact/
 <div style="display: none;" id="myModal" class="modal hide fade">
 <p>this is my email app here...</p>
</div>
----------
# this is the button on a 'show' page where i want someone to push to bring up the contents of the above page in the modal.
<a data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Launch Email</a>
```

Comment: @amitamb - no I have not tried IFrame yet but I have seen solutions on searches so I think I will try that first as it seems easiest.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, so the trick here is that the "other page" is probably a result of a Rails controller action which would normally render the page on a separate URL, right?  Yet bootstrap assumes that when you click the link, its HTML exists already on the current page.

So how to handle this?  You'll need to make the controller request via AJAX (`link_to ... :remote => true` is a good place to start) and change the controller to have its contents added to a div on current the page somewhere. Once that's done, the code you have above, or something like it (or like what is documented on the Bootstrap page) will do what you want.

EDIT: adding specific example, in my case opening the edit user page in a bootstrap modal (using Devise gem for authentication):

`app/views/devise/registrations/_edit.html.erb:`

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="user-edit">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">x</button>
    <h2>Edit User</h2>
  </div>

  <%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => {:method => :put}) do |f| %>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= devise_error_messages! %>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :name %><br/>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
      </div>

      <div>
         <%= f.label :email %><br/>
        <%= f.email_field :email %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password, :autocomplete => "off" %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
      </div>

      <div>
        <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br/>
        <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
      <%= f.button "Update", :class => "btn btn-primary", :data => { :dismiss => "modal"} %>
      <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>
    </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

`app/views/devise/registrations/edit.js.erb:`

```
$("#main").before("<%= escape_javascript(render "edit", :formats => [:html]) %>");
$("#user-edit").modal();
```

and, the link that invokes it from any page (I have it in the nav now:

```
<li><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_user_registration_path, :remote => true %></li>
```

Comment: You are right - this is an email form like a contact us page that I want to render in a modal. I just want to allow a user to email another user when they are on their page through a form. thanks for submitting this but unfortunately i am a noob and have no idea how I would do this. I have used :remote => true but as for "change the controller to have its contents added to a div" I am not sure what you mean.

Comment: does anyone have a step by step example of how this works? :)