# Changing Devise for Bootstrap modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I found this link [Link to another page using Twitter Bootstrap jquery modal in rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10318949/link-to-another-page-using-twitter-bootstrap-jquery-modal-in-rails) and here is completely what I need - registration and others using Bootstrap modal and Devise.

I made that steps, but it doesn't popup, but redirects me to another page and shows not proper page.

It behaves really strange, it opens NOT MINE form.

_new.html.erb

```
<div class="modal hide fade in" id="sign_up">

<%= form_for resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name),do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>
....
 <% end %>
```

Create new.js.erb:

```
      $("#main").before("<%= escape_javascript(render "new", :formats => [:html]) %>");
      $("#sign_up").modal();
```

and link_to :

```
       <%= link_to "Sign up", new_user_registration_path, :remote => true %>
```

and in application.html.erb:

```
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all" %>
   <%= javascript_include_tag 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js' %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

**EDITED.**
     In my logs: 
            Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as JS
           Rendered devise/registrations/new.js.erb (15.6ms)
           Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 31ms

```
      ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial devise/new with {:locale=>[:en], :f
       ormats=>[:js, :html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee, :rabl]}. Searched in:

     * "D:/print_it_green/app/views"
    * "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.1.0/app/views"
       ):
        1: $("#sign_up").before("<%= escape_javascript(render "devise/new", :formats
       => [:html]) %>");
         2: $("#sign_up").modal();
      app/views/devise/registrations/new.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_devise_registration
       s_new_js_erb___312569811_25856784'
```

Where is problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what folder are your files? If you're going to use Devise then you can use `rails generate devise:views` to customize the views. Then put your `new` partial and `new` js file in that folder.

You can also [configure the controller](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) if you need to, but if you create the views, then Devise should automatically point to the Devise folder that the aforementioned command creates.

In your jQuery, you'd put `render "devise/registrations/new"` instead of just `"new"`.

Comment: in devise folder. I generated them. one moment, I will try it.

Comment: What does your server say? It should say "Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#new as JS".

Answer (score 3):

In **new.js.erb** you're trying to inject the modal code in a section called `#main`.

Add an empty `<div>` tag with `id=main` to the page you're calling this from, and it should work.